Pasado de moda-word use and context
I know ''pasado de moda means old-fashioned especially with clothes at least. I reviewed Spanishdict and the RAE. THe latter states:
pasar, o pasarse, algo de moda

locs. verbs. Perder actualidad o vigencia.

Spanishdict's example sentences convey the contexts of fashion,people,and words being outdated.
https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/pasado%20de%20moda
I wonder can it be used with music e.g.''para mi ese género de música es pasado de moda''. Also, in Spanishdict I see it used with estar and ser
.For music would it be ''es/estar pasado de moda''?
Presumably,ser as it is a state of being but its' transitory nature is confusing.
Alternatively but along similar lines, I know of ''estar en boga'' or to be in vogue in English. Can this also be used for music? I don't see it used with music in Spanishdict or elsewhere.
https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/boga.
I presume it is used with ''estar'' and not ''ser''.

It does not mean old fashioned always. It means: out of style, no longer in style or outdated, yes.  We also say in English: to be in style. in vogue in English is very "posh". It can be used for anything that is a style of something. These kitchens are out of style.

Yes, in English,something considered  old fashioned can mean it to be outdated or out of style,I agree. A less formal expression for in vogue may be trendy

Sure, trendy is okay too.

Yes, it is frequently used "Esa música está pasada de moda", you can Google it and you will find multiple examples.
About the expression "estar en boga", it is not very usual to heard it in colloquial languaje, it is more common to hear "esta música está de moda".
